# How to restrict access to dev/mem on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to write a program that controls the access to the GPIO pins of my raspberry pi. In other words, any process that needs to access a GPIO pin will have to go through the service I am writing. I know that in order to access and control a GPIO pin, a library/program needs to access the /dev/mem file.

Is there a way to protect this file or restrict the access to it by ANY other process?

Comment: If a device driver claims a PIO pin using the pinctrl subsystem, then that pin will not be available through the sysfs GPIO interface (or to any other driver).  As for **/dev/mem/**, there's only the standard user & group permissions for a file.  *"I know that in order to access and control a GPIO pin, a library/program needs to access the /dev/mem file"* -- That's not true, and it's the worst (non-portable and potentially dangerous) method.

Comment: @sawdust unfortunately it seems to be the norm on the Raspberry Pi to directly manipulate the mmios for GPIO... I believe people did this before the GPIO drivers came out and it kind of stuck as the 'correct' way to do things.

Comment: I think you could prevent it from being built into kernel.